# what's the shortest python oneliner for making sure a folder exists and if not creates it recursively?

Tags: python, path

what's the shortest python oneliner for making sure a folder exists and if not creates it recursively? 
I can do it with two lines using the `pathlib` module

```
from pathlib import Path
Path('test/blah/foo/bar/').mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
```

can you do it in one line? 
having it in one line to use in various educational notebooks, where using two lines obscures the purpose of the code

Comment: you can use `os.makedirs('test/blah/foo/bar/', exist_ok=True)` refer [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs)

Comment: @Shijith still requires import os

Comment: @AviadRozenhek There is no way around it (unless you're doing it from an ipython console or a Jupyter notebook, which can natively supports shell commands)

Comment: There's no built-in that will do this—you're going to have to `import` something. Seems like a minor detail to me.